# Understanding "this" within callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback, this

I'm trying to understand what "this" refers through various code examples. So far, I know that "this" depends on who calls it or how it is called. For example:

```
let user = {
  firstName: "Ilya",
  sayHi() {
    let arrow = () => console.log(this.firstName);
    arrow();
  },
  sayHi2() {
    let func = function() {
      console.log(this.firstName)
    }
    return func;
  }
};

user.sayHi(); // Ilya
let hi = user.sayHi; 
hi(); // undefined 
user.func = user.sayHi2()
user.func() // Ilya
```

The above example makes sense to me and I also learned that arrow functions do not have **"this"** so it searches for **"this"** through its outer lexical environments.

Now, I'm trying "this" using callbacks.

```
let user = {
  firstName: "Bob",
  sayHi(func) {
    func()
  }
}

function hello() {
  console.log("hello " + this.firstName);
}

user.sayHi(hello);
user.sayHi(()=>{ console.log("hello " + this.firstName)});
```

Why do `this.firstName` return undefined? Doesn't **"this"** refer to the `user` object since `sayHi()` is called by the `user`? Or does **"this"** value different when the function is executed as callbacks?

Comment: *"Doesn't "this" refer to the user"*. Arrow functions have no explicit `this`

Comment: Arrow functions uses this in its outer lexical environment. So doesn't that mean it this will  reference the outer this of the sayHi() lexical environment?